# How to prevent javascript drawImage() from scaling image?

Tags: javascript, drawimage

My goal is simple:  Draw icons on top of a background image (specifically a map).

I'm creating a canvas and then using JavaScript to draw the icons on top of it.  Unfortunately when I load the icon it increases the scale substantially.  Here's my code:

```
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("WorldView");
  if(!canvas.getContext){return;}
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);};
  img.src = 'images/ship-icon small.png';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body width=100% style="text-align: center;" onload="draw()">
  <canvas id="WorldView" ></canvas>
</body>
```

Why is it increasing the scale automatically and how do I prevent it from doing that?  Also, on 'ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);' the '10,10' pushes it further than 10px, more like 50px.

Comment: It may be because you are setting the source after the img.onload.

Comment: @mulquin setting the src after onload is the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set any size for the canvas element so the it using the default size of 300 x 150 and if you are using CSS to set a size of the canvas scaling of its content will be the result.

Try doing:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("WorldView");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;   /// integer values
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

(or some other values if filling the window is not the intention).

and then remove the size setting from CSS.

Comment: I should have included my CSS too:  #WorldView {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-image: url(../WorldView/world.png);
 width: 1670px;
 height: 852px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

Comment: This was the problem.  I had only set the size of the canvas in CSS.  Setting it in the DOM solved the issue.  Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For those of you who need a responsive canvas element. (doing a webcam screenshot feature).
My solution was to print first the content in a temporary canvas like this :

```
originImageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
originImageCanvas.width = $(_video).outerWidth()
originImageCanvas.height = $(_video).outerHeight()
originImageCtx = originImageCanvas.getContext('2d')
originImageCtx.drawImage _video, 0, 0, originImageCanvas.width, originImageCanvas.height

hiddenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
hiddenCanvas.width = $(_video).outerWidth()
hiddenCanvas.height = $(_video).outerHeight()
ctx = hiddenCanvas.getContext('2d')

unless sourceX?
  sourceX = (hiddenCanvas.width / 2) - (sourceWidth / 2)

unless sourceY?
  sourceY = (hiddenCanvas.height / 2) - (sourceHeight / 2)

ctx.drawImage originImageCanvas, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight
```

Hope it can help anyone !